# PHP foreach based on array variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array and PHP code - this adds an `option` to a drop down list and works fine but this is one drop down list.

However, what I would like to achieve is for a separate drop down list to be created for each of the unique values in the array `[0]` in the array.

So based on the array below there would be three drop down lists, one for ACME, one for EDNON and one for VALUE and each list would be populated with information already included in the PHP code below.

**Array**

```
Array (
[4f5hfgb] => Array (
[0] => ACME
[1] => 4f5hfgb
[2] => Aberdeen
)
[sdf4ws] => Array (
[0] => ACME
[1] => sdf4ws
[2] => Birmingham 
)
[dfgdfg54] => Array (
[0] => EDNON
[1] => dfgdfg54
[2] => Birmingham 
)
[345bfg] => Array (
[0] => EDNON
[1] => 345bfg
[2] => Birmingham 
)
[345fgfd] => Array (
[0] => VALVE
[1] => 345fgfd
[2] => Birmingham 
)
)
```

**PHP**

```
echo "
    <span class='Question SelectBox'>
    <span class='qnum noshow'></span>
    <span class='qtext'>Option</span>
    <span class='shown'>
     <select class='combobox' id='option' name='option' data-placeholder=\"Option...\" '>
       <option value=\"\">Option...</option>";

    foreach ($tmp as $value) {
     echo "<option name='".$value[0]."' value='".$value[1]."'>".$value[2]."</option>";
    }
     echo"</select>
     </span>
     </span>
     <span class='clearfix'></span>";
```

**Attempted code**

I have tried modifying the code but this only produces one drop down and the options are duplicated:

```
foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    if($value[0]=='ACME'){
    echo "<option name='".$value[0]."' value='".$value[1]."'>".$value[2]."</option>";echo "<option name='".$value[0]."' value='".$value[1]."'>".$value[2]."</option>";
    }

}
```

I'm struggling to understand if this is actually possible.  Any advice, feedback and suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Maybe you want to add an `optgroup` for each of those sections of your array?

Comment: @quickshiftin - appreciate that but I would like to split out into seperate dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Original array of data
//------------------------------------------------------------
$a = array(
'4f5hfgb'  => array('ACME', '4f5hfgb', 'Aberdeen'),
'sdf4ws'   => array('ACME', 'sdf4ws', 'Birmingham'),
'dfgdfg54' => array('EDNON', 'dfgdfg54', 'Birmingham'),
'345bfg'   => array('EDNON', '345bfg', 'Birmingham'),
'345fgfd'  => array('VALVE', '345fgfd', 'Birmingham'));

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Group the options by 'name'
//------------------------------------------------------------
$aGroupedOptions = array();
foreach($a as $aRawOption) {
    list($sName, $sValue, $sOption) = $aRawOption;
    $aGroupedOptions[$sName][]      = array($sValue, $sOption);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Build the HTML
//------------------------------------------------------------
foreach($aGroupedOptions as $sName => $aOptions) {
    echo
    '<span class="Question SelectBox">
    <span class="qnum noshow"></span>
    <span class="qtext">Option</span>
    <span class="shown">
     <select class="combobox" id="option-' . $sName . '" name="option-' . $sName . '">';

    foreach($aOptions as $aOption) {
        list($sValue, $sOption) = $aOption;
        echo '<option name="'. $sName . '" value="' . $sValue . '">' .
             $sOption . '</option>';

     echo"</select>
     </span>
     </span>
     <span class='clearfix'></span>";
}
```

Comment: Personally I would reorganize the inbound array as I've done here, it's more expensive, but it makes the code easier to understand IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You want a **nested `foreach` loop**. An outer loop to create the dropdowns, and an inner loop to create the options:

```
foreach ($dropdowns as $options) {
    echo "<select ....>";
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo "<option>$option</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>
}
```

Stay safe against XSS attacks!